# Types of adjuncts - What can be adjoined to what and why?

Tags: generative-grammar, minimalism

In generative grammar, more specifically in GB and Minimalism, what are the possible types of adjuncts we can have and to which other categories can they be adjoined. E.g.: the man [next to him] many people would probably classify the bracketed string as a PP adjoined to the NP man. For me it is not entirely clear why one would exclude adjunction to the DP.

Comment: "The man" is an NP in which "man" is the head nominal. It is the latter that is modified by the PP "next to him" to give the nominal "man next to him".

Comment: I am fully aware of this standard analysis - but why adjoin to the NP node and not to DP, nP, numP or any other syntactic projection people have suggested in the nominal domain?

Comment: Evidence for what @BillJ says above is that, like other N-bars, "man next to him" can be antecedent for "one".  E.g., "the old man next to me and the young one, too".